# Запуск приложения без прав администратора

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sudo

Нужна помощь.

Имеется программа запущенная с правами суперпользователя(`Linux`).
Необходимо перезапустить ее из нее самой(т.е сама программа себя должна перезапустить) так,что бы права были не `sudo`,а права текущего пользователя.

Пробовал так:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->start("QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/test");
```

Ну или может есть способ во время выполнения программы сменить ей права из нее самой без перезапуска?

Comment: `$runuser -l user -c 'command'`, работает только если запускать от рута (ну то есть ваша ситуация)

Comment: для того, чтобы сбросить привилегии для текущего процесса достаточно просто сделать `setuid()`. для запускаемого процесса — смотри пример переопределения `QProcess::setupChildProcess()`. в обоих случаях самое непонятное — как ты будешь определять «текущего пользователя»... а вообще подход странный и попахивает [ошибкой XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: Вопрос помечен как "linux", а в тексте "test.exe"... Так всё-таки, о какой ОС идёт речь?

Comment: У вас концептуально что-то не так. Если программе не нужны привилегии рута, её точно не надо запускать через `sudo`. Если программе на старте абсолютно необходимы привилегии рута, то её надо запускать не через sudo, а путём установки suid бита на бинарник, а потом делать setuid()

Comment: Программа должна запуститься от рута для внесения ключей в системные файлы.А дальше уже например открыть пдф файл.Но Линукс не любит `GUI`  с правами `root`

Comment: C `$runuser -l user -c 'command'` сбиваются переменные окружения.А вот с `su user -c 'command'` вроде все нормально